Command to open an Outlook appointment, passing a specific start and end time
I want to open an Outlook appointment using a command line interface command and pass the start time and end time to it.
I found the method outlook.exe -c ipm.appointment -m user@contoso.com?subject=Test&body=Hello, but that passes an email subject, not not a start and end time.
I have looked here, without luck, do you know a method to do this?

Your problem is not with your programming code, so your question is off topic on this site.
